# What are some good options for decentralized databases?

Tags: javascript, storage, database

One issue I am facing right now is that I am not sure on a good, decentralized database. I will need a higher amount of storage to store my main data and I have looked at solutions like IPFS, gun.js but I am not sure exactly what benefits I would receive from using these.

Would it be appropriate to use a normal database and link to this data inside of my Solana account?

I am aware of the 10MB max size of a Solana account, however, this can be very expensive and I would rather have the security of a higher sized database being used.

Thanks!

Comment: The Blockchain is the decentralized database solution. But yes, storage is expensive. Check Shadow Drive also, it is built on top of the Solana consensus mechanism.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.